# How to make std::cin read only a part of the input?

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that's supposed to read one or two number digits from a line of input.
It looks like this:

```
int N = 0;
cin >> N;
int data[100];

for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cin.ignore(5, ' ') >> data[i];
    }

for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cout << data[i] << endl;
    }
```

And the input:

```
3
1111 22 3 4444 5555
1111 2 3 4444 5555
1111 22 33 4444 5555
```

The first input is the number of lines the program should expect.
After that, each input line looks like the ones above. From those, I want to extract the 2s or 22s. I've learnt about `cin.ignore` with which I can tell the program to skip a certain amount of characters and also specify and ending character (I think?). The 6th should be the first character and the space after 22 or 2 should be where it stops. If I put in the input above the array will get filled like this instead:

```
22
3
4444
```

And the program will already stop after I put in

```
3
1111 22 3 4444 5555
```

I'm a very very beginner and I'm pretty sure I messed up someting very obvious, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required here please!

Answer (score 2):

Read all and discard all but the one you need:

```
// ...

for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    int dummy;
    std::cin >> dummy >> data[i] >> dummy >> dummy >> dummy;
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore till the subsequent newline (`'\n'`) as well after ignoring till the first whitespace in a line in the input.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

constexpr auto max_streamsize = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();

int main() {
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    
    int data[100];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cin.ignore(max_streamsize, ' ') >> data[i];
        std::cin.ignore(max_streamsize, '\n');
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
}
```